# Robobrowser Login-Form Submission Unsuccessful or Incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, robobrowser

```
import re
import robobrowser
browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(parser = "html.parser", user_agent='Mozilla/5.0...')

browser.open('blah.com')

login_form=browser.get_form(class_='login')

email='realemailhere'
password='realpwhere'


login_form['email'].value=email
login_form['password'].value=password


login_form.serialize()        

print (login_form)

browser.submit_form(login_form)




allButtons=browser.get_links()

print(allButtons)
```

Seems like this should work ok. 
Have tried serialized and unserializd.
Sure the form classes are correct.
Need to log in, but get_links() returns nothing after submitting the form.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review the following online tutorial: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  
By crafting your title and question better you may get a quicker response and in turn may help other developers in the future.

Comment: Done @CharlesByrne